# Rebuild all JS files in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a Ionic 2 app and adding new features. But for some reason the features do not always show in my browser when using ionic serve.

Maybe I need to re-build the entire app?

```
[18:01:56]  build started ... 
[18:01:56]  transpile update started ... 
[18:01:56]  transpile update finished in 38 ms 
[18:01:56]  webpack update started ... 
[18:02:06]  webpack update finished in 9.82 s 
[18:02:06]  build finished in 9.86 s
```

This is what happens. Maybe it transpiles only some files. Is there any way to force Ionic to rebuild all files (JS, ...)?

Comment: There is a bug I noticed in the latest versions of ionic cli or ionic app scripts not sure that causes the html to not be updated on each rebuild. Are you talking about this?